# Set Y-axis scale MS chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using **MS chart,** basically a line chart.

I am also using label format to show numbers upto 2 decimal places using

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)";
```

and property IsStartedFromZero is set to false.

This works for most of the cases.

But if i plot using `value (.1,.1,.09) or (.25,.25.22),` it shows duplicate values in Y-axis scale. This happens due to formatting of label.

In excel,there is option of setting major unit under format axis option, charts are properly created in excel if Major unit is set to 0.01 (fixed)

how can this be set in microsoft chart, i want to create the same using MS chart.

Tried `chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = .01,` but this doesn't works.

Any other suggestion to fix this.